# Delphi Form with custom constructor as the mainform?

Tags: delphi, constructor, tform

I want to have a MainForm that is derived from a BaseForm that has a custom constructor. Since this is the Mainform, it is created by a call to *Application.CreateForm(TMyMainForm, MyMainForm)* in the *.dpr file. However, my custom constructor is not called during form creation.

Obviously, it works fine, if I call *MyMainForm := TMyMainForm.Create(AOwner)*. Can I not use a form with custom constructor as the main form ?

```
TBaseForm = class(TForm)
  constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent; AName:string);reintroduce;
end;

TMyMainForm = class(TBaseForm)
  constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent);reintroduce;
end;  

constructor TBaseForm.Create(AOwner:TComponent);

begin;
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

constructor TMyMainForm.Create(AOwner:TComponent);

begin;
  inherited Create(AOwner, 'Custom Constructor Parameter');
end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Application.CreateForm()` cannot call a `reintroduce`'d constructor.  When creating a new object, it calls the `TComponent.Create()` constructor and expects polymorphism to call any derived constructors.  By `reintroduce`'ing your custom constructor, you are not part of the polymorphic call chain. `reintroduce` exposes a completely new method that simply has the same name as an inherited method but is not related to it.

To do what you are attempting, don't use `reintroduce` for your constructors.  Create a separate constructor in your Base form, and then have your MainForm `override` the standard constructor and call your custom Base constructor, eg:

```
TBaseForm = class(TForm)
  constructor CreateWithName(AOwner: TComponent; AName: string); // <-- no reintroduce needed since it is a new name
end;

TMyMainForm = class(TBaseForm)
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override; // <-- not reintroduce
end;  

constructor TBaseForm.CreateWithName(AOwner: TComponent; AName: string);
begin;
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  // use AName as needed...
end;

constructor TMyMainForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin;
  inherited CreateWithName(AOwner, 'Custom Constructor Parameter');
end;
```

Comment: Most of the time, all people are trying to do through this approach is initialize members in the derived classes through the constructor. I don't recommend this. Instead, you can also define public properties and initialize them after the derived form is created. It's an extra line or two of code, but so what?

Comment: The advantage of a constructor with parameters is that you **must** pass something, so you can't forget to pass the required settings. Setting properties can be forgotten. This is not because people want to save typing a few lines, but simply because it is the better strategy, IMO.

Comment: Reason for this plan is exactly the one noted by Rudy,  @RudyVelthuis  My intention here is to have a common baseform that has background, handles NCHitTest, remembers last position, size etc (writing/reading from registry) and derive all my future projects from that. Is there a better way than the strategy above?

Comment: @ss2006 why do you need constructor parameters? What will you pass?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - A descriptive name of the project which would be used by the `BaseForm` to create the registry keys and say save the position and size of the form (to simplify remembering the user's preferences from the previous session), or depending on the string use different `createparams`

Comment: @ss2006 You could use virtual class methods to supply this information. I think that's how I'd go about doing it. It's much of a muchness. Comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

In order for a form to become the VCL main form, it must be created via a call to `Application.CreateForm`. That in turn calls the virtual constructor declared in `TComponent`. So, there's no way to get a different constructor to be called for the VCL main form.

One option is that presented by Remy. To override the constructor declared in `TComponent`, and call a different constructor passing extra parameters. That can be a constructor in the same class, or an inherited constructor from a base class.

Another option here would be to use abstract class methods on a base class. For instance,

```
type
  TMainFormBase = class(TForm)
  protected
    class function ProjectName: string; virtual; abstract;
    class function RegKeyPath: string; virtual; abstract;
  end;
```

In your derived classes you would override these abstract methods. Instead of setting properties in the constructor, code in the base form class could just call these methods. Of course, if you needed to do work in the constructor, you could perfectly well call these methods from the constructor.

Personally I have a prejudice against adding new constructors to classes that already have virtual constructors. The virtual constructor paradigm leads you towards using that single virtual constructor, and nothing else. If you start adding different constructors further down the hierarchy then it's just all too easy to end up with trouble caused by the wrong constructor being called when instantiating virtually.