# Delphi - Form Properties empty on FormCreate when set from other Form

Tags: oop, delphi

Here is an interesting case.

Have the Login Form, where some variables values are set, like company_id and SelectedlanguageCode, the idea is to pass this values to the MainForm properties to make things fast (selected language code go to Database to query), this values will be immediately required in the FormCreate Event, but here the values are missing, but debugging after the CreateForm-event the values just show.

Here is the Project Source Code:

```
{$R *.res}

Var
  LoginOK: Boolean = False;
  sCompanyId: integer;
  sSelectedLanguageCode: string;
begin
  // The login form is created and show up
  // --------------------------------------

  fLogin := TfLogin.Create(nil);
  try
    // Show login form. When it closes, see if login worked.
    fLogin.ShowModal;
    LoginOK := fLogin.CanLogin;         
    sCompanyId := fLogin.pCompanyId;
    sSelectedLanguageCode := fLogin.gDefaultLanguageCode;
  finally
    fLogin.DisposeOf;
  end;

  if not LoginOK then
    Halt;    // Login failed - terminate application.

  Application.Initialize;

  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TfMain, fMain);
  // Here the properties of Main are set with the values, 
  // when debugging the properties get the values, you can
  // see the actual values when hovering over the property
  fMain.gSelectedLanguage := sSelectedLanguageCode;
  fMain.gUserCompany := sCompanyId;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

But as mentioned, in the CreateForm of Main, the properties are empty...
And... after CreateForm event, the properties have the actual value.

I need this values in CreateForm event because some methods will be invoked and need to send them...

I appreciate the answer about what is going on to understand what am I doing wrong, or if that have a good reason to be just like that then... if you can give me another approach to solve this requirement, thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a chicken and egg dilemma. You can not set the properties before the form is created, but you need those values already during form creation. So, place those variables in the main forms unit as global vars (shiver). Then you can set them before form is created and your main form can read them when it needs them.

Comment: When `Application.CreateForm` returns, the form has already been created and it's `FormCreate` has executed. Clearly they can't be available in `FormCreate` when you're not setting them until *after* `FormCreate` has already been run.

Comment: Tom, that is the way it is done, the code provided is the Applications code, it creates the Login-form first, then after the user log-in it creates the Main form and assign the login's values, release login-form and show Main. I had the values all the time in the Main properties to use them, that works perfect, but It was until I needed them in the CreateForm Event when I realized that specifically there the values are not available yet, just there.

Comment: you could try to override the constructor of fMain so you can pass the values in the constructor. Instead of Application.CreateForm() it will be something like this then:  fMain = TfMain.Create(Application, sSelectedLanguageCode, sCompanyID) Info about how to do this you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132808/delphi-form-with-custom-constructor-as-the-mainform

Answer (score 1):

OK, so instead of having your initialisation code in the formCreate, move it all to a method on the main form (e.g. init()).
then in the line before you application.run you can have
mainform.init;
or
mainform.init(sSelectedLanguageCode, sCompanyId);

I always split out creation from initialisation.  If the form is shown and isn't initialised you can raise an error then.  i.e. in the onShow, if no company ID - tell the user there was an error and close the app....